# How to access current plot color in pgfplots

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, color

I'm looking for a way to access the current plot index of pgfplots in order for a subsequent draw command to use that plots color.

```
\documentclass[]{standalone}
\usepackage{%
  tikz,%
  pgfplots,%
}
\pgfplotsset{%
  compat=1.17,%
  every axis/.append style={%
  colormap name=viridis,%
  colorbar,%
  cycle list={[samples of colormap=5]},%
  % cycle from colormap manual style,
  },% end every axis/.append style
  emphasizey/.code args={#1:#2}{% higlight a certrain range of y values
    \pgfplotsextra{%
      \shade[%
        inner color=white,%
        % /pgfplots/index of colormap=\pgfplots@listindex,% yields 'Unknown function' error
        /pgfplots/index of colormap=\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/cycle list shift},% yields 'Did not find a suitable input source pos in a 'of colormap' specification. Did you forget the 'source pos'?'
        outer color=.,%
        opacity=.5,%
        ] ({axis cs:\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmin},#1} -| {axis description cs:0,0})
        rectangle ({axis cs:\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmax},#2} -| {axis description cs:1,0});
    },% end pgfplotsextra
  },% end emphasizey
}% end pgfplotsset

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[]
    \begin{axis}[%
      point meta=f(x),%
      ]
      \addplot+ [mark=*, emphasizey={5:15}] {x^2};
      \addplot+ [mark=*, emphasizey={-3:3}] {x};
    \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Now what I want this code to do is draw the first shaded box using the first plot's blue color and the second shaded box to use the second plot's red color, but they are both blue.

Also I get following compiler error:

```
Package PGF Math Error: Unknown function `listindex' (in '@listindex').
```

I tried to use `\pgfplotsvalueof{}` and even introduce a custom counter and tried to make it step up with each plot and use that to point to the `index of colormap`.

I'd really appreciate if someone shed some light on this issue as I simply wasn't able to extract more information from the source code than that pgfplots uses `\pgfplots@listindex` to number plots.

BTW: The purpose of this is to highlight the avarage +- stddev of, say, a time series...

EDIT:
I have created an example that yields the output that I want to achieve however i manually set the colors instead of the automated way that I would prefer. I'd like to be able to just omit the  `with <color>` and still get the same result as showcased.

```
\documentclass[]{standalone}
\usepackage{%
  tikz,%
  pgfplots,%
}
\pgfplotsset{%
  compat=1.17,%
  emphasizey/.code args={#1:#2 with #3}{% higlight a certrain range of y values
    \pgfplotsextra{%
      \shade[%
        inner color=white,%
        outer color=#3,%
        opacity=.5,%
        ] ({axis cs:\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmin},#1} -| {axis description cs:0,0})
        rectangle ({axis cs:\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmax},#2} -| {axis description cs:1,0});
    },% end pgfplotsextra
  },% end emphasizey
}% end pgfplotsset

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[]
    \begin{axis}[%
      point meta=f(x),%
      ]
      \addplot+ [mark=*, emphasizey={5:15 with blue}] {x^2};
      \addplot+ [mark=*, emphasizey={-3:3 with red}] {x};
    \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: What it should look like]

Comment: See the [cycle list shift] key (page 220).  It is used as the increment for \addplot.

Comment: I tried what I thought it is you suggested. However I understand `pgfplots` doesn't use that key internally to increment the plot color so it just holds the initial value. It also yields another error. Please see the edited post above.

Comment: The easy solution is to specify the color in \addplot instead of using the cycle list,

Comment: I understand you suggest to specifically set a color for the plot and set that same color for the drawing command? That certainly works, however i was hoping for an automated way rather than a simple one.